# Can a Sharepoint 2013 Online Publishing site be configured to have a custom domain?

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, domain

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm a Sharepoint rookie learning as I go.

So, I have built a Publishing site in Sharepoint 2013 Online, and now I want to setup a custom domain for it.

My research on the internet only returns results on how to set a domain to a Public site, not for a Publishing site - is it because you can't do it for Publishing sites, or is it the same approach?

Also, I want to allow anonymous users to be able to browse the site. I've found a couple tutorials on that subjects, but I can't find in my Sharepoint Administration Center the option mentioned in both tutorials - the option I can't find is "Application Management" ->"Web Application Management"

And these are the tutorials I'm following (first is 2013, and 2nd is 2010):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shyjumohan/anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/07/16/how-to-enable-anonymous-access-to-your-sharepoint-site/

Answer (score 0):

If your publishing site is intended to be a public site then yes, you can configure a custom domain.  However, at the moment you cannot configure custom domains for any private/extranet sites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dave. The site is indeed intended to be a public site - so having a Publishing site that is intended to be public, do I need to configure anything else than configuring the custom domain?

Comment: The O365 admin site includes some good guidance on getting the DNS configured for your custom domain - once that is done then you need to tell O365 to use it for SharePoint.

Comment: Just wanted to complete the details by saying the site is not in premises, but instead we're using Sharepoint 2013 Online - are there any restrictions due to this?

Comment: Just for a change I managed to read your initial question so yes, my response applies to SharePoint online :)

Comment: Dave, I really appreciate your input, thank you. I've been following [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-suite-help/use-a-custom-domain-for-your-sharepoint-online-public-website-address-HA102818661.aspx) step by step guide, unsuccessfully - in step 3 I have to place the URL to the Sharepoint site that is going to have the custom domain - CNAME table. The example they give is _name.sharepoint.com_ but my site is located at _name.sharepoint.com/sites/TheSite_ - which URL must I type in CNAME table then? This may be where things are going wrong...

Comment: Hmm - CNAME etc is not my strong point but as I understand it you cannot point a CNAME to a sub-site.  This will essentially point any traffic for that domain to your Office 365 so that is where you manage which site they go to.